# Can I monitor a nodejs app from another nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs app which is minified ( Paas app ) and is hosted to work with a third party library to view PDF files.

The issue I'm facing is the this app's code is minified as I mentioned and it's not easy to unminify its code and write my own to log or monitor that app.

So, I'm thinking to write my own nodejs app that possibly monitors this app that's hosted in Azure app service, I need to monitor all the https requests and IO operations that are happening within this app. My question here is that even possible? can Pm2 do the job in my case?

Comment: Do you control the port the paas app listens on?

Comment: I'd say yes because we host it in Azure but since it's minified I can't tell if it tries to listen to another server's port or not. Does that answer your question?